# zip multiple files with the same name but different extensions

Tags: command-line, zip, filename

I have a folder that contains files with the same file name but different extensions (.jpg and .eps). Each .eps has a matching .jpg with the same name and I want to zip them together in pairs. (The zip file should have the same name.)

The naming convention is like this: 1.eps 1.jpg 2.eps 2.jpg ...etc.

I want to create something like this: 1.zip (containing 1.eps and 1.jpg) 2.zip (containing 2.eps and 2.jpg

I am using MAC OS X. I want to automate the process cause I have thousands of files.

I am currently doing it manually by selecting two files at a time compress them and then rename. So I need something to find the files with the same name automatically within a folder, zip them together in a single zip file, and use the same name for the zip.

Comment: This site is for Ubuntu Linux questions.  Mac OS questions should be asked  at http://apple.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming Bash, this may work for you:

```
for i in *.eps; do  zip "${i%.*}.zip" "${i%.*}".*; done
```

Comment: Thank you this worked fine! You saved me from a lot of pain!